# Restarting an Azure Stream Analytics job without loosing data

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

If I am stopping an Azure Stream Analytics Job to scale the streaming units, once I restart the job, how can I assure that the events which it hasn't read during that interval are read again from the event hub?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done using [start options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/start-job#start-options) and choosing to start from the point where it last stopped.